# Open popup in parent component while having a click in the child component

Tags: vue.js, events, emit

I was wondering how it is possible to open a popup if the element that is being clicked is sitting in the child component. Basically, I have smth like this:

```
//Child

<button @click="openPopup">Open</button>

export default {
  methods: {
    openPopup() {
      this.$emit('openPopup');
    }
  }
}

    //Parent
    <popup v-show="isShown"></popup>
   export default {
    data() {
      return {
       isShown:false
      }
    }
```

So basically I can see that the event is being emitted but have no idea how to apply it in order to change the isShown value

Comment: You can listen to events with @ like <popup @openPopup="doSomeMethod"> check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61866499/click-event-as-props-in-vue-js/61876713#61876713

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

Child Component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button @click="openPopup(true)">Open</button>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
// ...

export default {
  // ...
  methods: {
    openPopup(flag) {
      this.$emit("openPopupInParent", flag);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Parent Component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <popup v-show="isShown" @openPopupInParent="showPopup"></popup>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
// ...

export default {
  // ...
  methods: {
    showPopup(flag) {
      this.isShown = flag
    }
  }
};
</script>
```